# CSV file - Have Pandas and Python module

Tags: python, pandas

so thanks to some great help I am able to manipulate a CSV file. However, a tutorial I was linked to seemed a bit complicated because they're posting several bits of code to get rows and columns for their data, without showing their full code.

So, this is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("TB_burden_countries_2018-03-06.csv")
df = df[df["country"] == "Zimbabwe"]
print(df)
```

What should I be writing if I want a specific column (example would be "e_pop_num"?) The website I used did:

```
df2.loc["Alaska":"Arkansas","2005":"2007"]
```

I changed the code to:

```
df.loc["Zimbwabe":"Zimbwabe","e_pop_num":"e_pop_num"]
```

And it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I've chucked down both of the df.loc codes down, and it just spits out the entire file, rather than specific lines. This is what the code looks like now:

`import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("TB_burden_countries_2018-03-06.csv")
df.loc[df["country"]=="Afghanistan","e_pop_num"]
print(df)`

Comment: Heres the other code, too:

`import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("TB_burden_countries_2018-03-06.csv", index_col=["country"])
df.loc["Afghanistan","e_pop_num"]
print(df)`

It spits out the entire file, too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need set index by column `country` first by parameter `index_col` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv("TB_burden_countries_2018-03-06.csv", index_col=['country'])
```

And then select all rows between `Alaska-Arkansas` and columns between `2005-2007`:

```
df.loc["Alaska":"Arkansas","2005":"2007"]
```

If need select only one row, one column for scalar output:

```
df.loc["Zimbwabe","e_pop_num"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the countries you want to select and the columns them:

```
df = df.loc[df[country]=="Zimbabwe","e_pop_num"]
```

edit: Forgot to rewrite the data frame using "df="

If you don't want to overwrite your data frame you can call as you want:

```
df2 = df.loc[df[country]=="Zimbabwe","e_pop_num"]
```